# Picklist not populating with Global Set values

Tags: picklist

Customizing Opportunities, I have two different picklist fields that both reference the same Global Set.  Both on the same layout and record type, one works the other doesn't.
[image]

Current GC works as expected, Target GC is the one not working.  I've checked every setting I can think to set and these are identical.  Why won't it work?
[image]

I validated that it was added in the Record Type for use:
[image]

Comment: On the recordtype did you add picklist values for the other field?

Comment: Yes, see record type screen above.

Answer (score 0):

Picklist PM is here. I was able to reproduce the issue you are describing, it seems like a bug on our side unfortunately.

I would suggest opening a case, so we can properly address it.

Thank you!